# How to disable or add specific classes in a ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question can I somehow disable a specific class or enable one in a unordered list here is my code

```
<section>
    <ul class="portfolio_filters">
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="*">show all</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".new">New Logos</a></li>                                          <!--lightbox2-->
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".black ">Black & White</a></li>                            <!--lightbox3-->
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".industrial">Industrial</a></li>                            <!--lightbox3-->
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".mix">Mix</a></li>                                           <!--lightbox4-->
         </ul>
</section>
```

For example if i want to disable class lightbox in this list

```
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".black ">Black & White</a></li>
```

and I have this linked to that list

```
<div class="black col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="portfolio_item"> <a href="images/portfolio/gcgarage.jpg" class="lightbox lightbox3 "> <img src="images/portfolio/gcgarage.jpg" alt="Automotive & Luxury">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="desc">
                <h4>Garage Carrosserie Perle du Lac</h4><p>
                <span class="cross"></span> </div>
            </div>
     </a> </div>
</div>
```

How to make it so that if I click on the Black and White list all items with 2 classes will lose their 2th class(i want) and will be with that filtered class I want without having to remove the lightbox class to my image?

Comment: *"all items with 2 classes "* - what is *item* here?

Answer (score 0):

Select items, which have black OR white class:

```
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".black, .white">Black OR White</a></li>
```

Select items, which have black AND white class:

```
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".black.white">Black & White</a></li>
```

Comment: thanks for you help , i can use this but i have a problem that if i click on a image when on full screen and want to go to the next image it shows me the "in same class" mate of the file for example

Comment: ----     its lightbox and lightbox3 class when i go the this list  and click over it it will show me this picture and when i want to show me the next image to it in that list it shows me all lightbox class mates and lightbox3 in the same time i want to disable this when on specific list exm <li><a href="#" data-filter=".black "> black </a><li> to show only lightbox3 class even when a file has 2 lightboxes is this possible , thanks in advance